# Building on Docker Hub ignores context path when copying files

Tags: django, docker, dockerhub

I am trying to upload a Django app to Docker Hub. On the local machine (Ubuntu 18.04) everything works fine, but on Docker Hub there is an issue that the requirements.txt file cannot be found.

**Local machine:**

```
sudo docker-compose build --no-cache
```

**Result (it's okay):**

```
Step 5/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 5542d55caeae
Step 6/7 : RUN file="$(ls -1 )" && echo $file
 ---> Running in b85a55aa2640
Dockerfile db.sqlite3 hello_django manage.py requirements.txt venv
Removing intermediate container b85a55aa2640
 ---> 532e91546d41
Step 7/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in e940ebf96023
Collecting Django==3.2.2....
```

**But, Docker Hub:**

```
    Step 5/7 : COPY . .
---> 852fa937cb0a
Step 6/7 : RUN file="$(ls -1 )" && echo $file
---> Running in 281d9580d608
README.md app config docker-compose.yml
Removing intermediate container 281d9580d608
---> 99eaafb1a55d
Step 7/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
---> Running in d0e180d83772
[91mERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
Removing intermediate container d0e180d83772
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

**app/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code
COPY . .
RUN file="$(ls -1 )" && echo $file
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**docker-composer.yml**

```
version: '3'
    services:
      web:
          build:
            context: app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
          volumes:
            - ./app/:/code/
          ports:
            - "8000:8000"
          env_file:
            - ./config/.env.dev
          command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Project Structure:

[image: img_ Structure]

**UPDATE:**
Docker is building from Github.
File requirements.txt is in the GitHub repository (app folder), but for some reason during build Docker Hub copies files from the project root folder and not the contents of the app folder.

**Github:**
https://github.com/sigalglebru/django-on-docker

Comment: How are you triggering or starting the "Docker Hub" case?

Comment: Can you share with us the actual github repository?

Comment: @larsks Github: https://github.com/sigalglebru/django-on-docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze Docker is buiding from Github. File requirements.txt is in the GitHub repository (app folder), but for some reason during build Docker Hub copies files from project root folder and not the contents of the app folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to tell Docker Hub where to find your build context.

When you run `docker-compose build` locally, `docker-compose` reads your `docker-compose.yml` file and knows to build inside the `app` directory, because you've explicitly set the build context:

```
build:
  context: app
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

When you build on Docker Hub, by default it will assume the build
context is the top level of your repository. If you set the path to
your `Dockerfile` to, e.g., `app/Dockerfile`, this is equivalent to
running:

```
docker build -f app/Dockerfile .
```

If you try that, you'll see if fail the same way. Rather than setting
the path to the `Dockerfile`, you need to set the path to the build
context to the `app` directory. For example:

[image]

(Look at the "Build Context" column).

When configured correct, your repository builds on Docker Hub without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I found solution:

**I just copied files from./app to the mounted volume, and little changed context, but still don't understand why it worked fine on the local machine**

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code
COPY ./app .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  python:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```